# Option clash for package color. \RequirePackage

Tags: color, incompatibility

I'm very new to LaTeX, and I'm having a problem which seems to originate from the following lines of code.

```
\RequirePackage[usenames]{color}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{nomencl}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
```

Option clash for package color. `\RequirePackage` error ocurred
at line `\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}`. Any idea?

**Corresponding log output is this**:

```
l.73 \RequirePackage
                    {fancyhdr}
The package color has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [usenames]
Adding the global options:
  ,usenames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A side note (probably not a solution to your problem, but important nonetheless): you wrote that you were new to LaTeX, but you use `\RequirePackage`, which is most commonly used only in class files (`.cls`) or packages (`.sty`); the common way to load a package in a `.tex` file is with `\usepackage`. Did you mean to use `\usepackage` instead of `\RequirePackage`?

Answer (score 8):

`fancyhdr` has nothing to do with the problem. Some package you load *earlier* already loads `color` without the `usenames` option.

The error message shows `\RequirePackage`, because this command scans for a possible optional argument; the complete syntax is

```
\RequirePackage[<options>]{<package>}[<YY>/<MM>/<DD>]
```

So when processing your command, LaTeX absorbs `\RequirePackage[usenames]{color}` and examines the next token in order to see if it is `[`. Since it isn't, it processes the call and stops because of the error; the error message shows the last token read by TeX.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says what is wrong and what should be done to fix it. Try changing the `\documentclass` declaration to something similar to

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,usenames]{article}
```

The exact declaration will vary but essentially adding the option `usenames` should fix the issue.